# Get com_contacts item by id?

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, custom-module, com-contacts

I need to get a com_contacts item the same way Joomla does (so I can re-use a template for example). I know I can get the item by querying the database directly, but that won't prepare things the same way Joomla das in com_content.

I can get contacts by *category* id fine with:

```
require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_contact/helpers/route.php';
JLoader::import('joomla.application.component.model');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_contact/models', 'ContentModel');
$categoryModel = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Category', 'ContactModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$categoryModel->setState('category.id', 53);
$categoryModel->setState('list.ordering', 'a.name');
$categoryModel->setState('list.direction', 'asc');
$categoryModel->setState('filter.published', 1);
$contacts = $categoryModel->getItems();
echo '<pre><tt>';print_r($contacts[0]);
```

How would I get a contact item by it's item id?

TIA!

Comment: To make it somewhat clearer: "same way Joomla does" meaning also including params, attribs, jcfields (custom fields) properties for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get single contact by ID, use Contact model:

```
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_contact/models', 'ContactModel');
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Contact', 'ContactModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$model->setState('contact.id', $contactId);
$model->setState('params', $params);
$contact = $model->getItem();
```

Where `$contactId` is the contact's ID and `$params` is the params. Params must be a Registry object. You can create a new Registry object or use app/component params, depending on your needs:

```
use Joomla\Registry\Registry;
$params = new Registry;
```

or

```
$params = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
```

or

```
use Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper;
$params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_contact');
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer.
Still, I get an error: __clone method called on non-object in /htdocs/components/com_contact/models/contact.php on line 245

Comment: Ah, I see. $model->setState('params', $params); seems to be required.

Comment: Had to add tags like this:
`$tags = new JHelperTags;
$tags->getItemTags('com_contact.contact', $contactId);`