# How can I call com_contact fields in an article view?

Tags: custom-field, com-contacts, com-fields

We have linked the author to `com_contacts` and now I want to show an author image which will be a custom field in `com_contacts`.

I was able to show it as a `com_user` custom field using the following code:

```
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', JFactory::getUser($author), true);

foreach($fields as $field) {
    $fields[$field->name] = $field;
}

$profilePicture = $fields['profilepicture50x50']->value;
echo $profilePicture;
```

But this does not help me if I want to use `com_contacts`.  I tried changing it to

```
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contacts.contact', JFactory::getUser($author), true);
```

But when I look in the API I do not see an API helper in that way.  I can get the author ID from the current page.

By using `$author = $displayData['item']->created_by;`
or by using `$displayData['contact_link']` to find the entire `com_contact` URL

Can anyone direct me to the correct API page or help me to understand how I could call such a field?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will still work, but you just need to pass a `contact` object as the second parameter to your call

```
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields(...);
```

Unfortunately afaik there is no API around `contact` the way there is around `user`, so it's a bit more complex to get it.

I got it by doing a database query (as in [Selecting data using JDatabase](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23214/get-com-contacts-item-by-id)) to find the `#__contact_details` table `id` (which I set to `$contactId`) where `created_by` = `user_id` in the `contact_details` table. Then I used JTable to get the `contact` object:

```
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_contact/tables');
$contact = JTable::getInstance('Contact', 'ContactTable', array());
if ($contact->load($contactId))
{
    JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
    $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contact.contact', $contact, true);
}
```

Then your code works as before.

I guess you have specific reasons for using Contact rather than User, but you obviously have to be careful as you can assign the same User to 2 or more Contact records.

(Once you get the contact id you can get the contact object using the contact model instead, as described in [Get com_contacts item by id?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23214/get-com-contacts-item-by-id).)